# Is it possible to use 'wp_insert_post' function within a for loop?

Tags: functions, api, wp-insert-post

I want to insert as a custom post type some data fethced from an API, I store that data and then pass it trough a for loop, then I use the loop data to create an array to pass it to wp_insert_post function, but it does not work, not even a single post is created, the code I'm trying to run is like this:

```
$url = "https://api_endpoint";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($response); $i++) { 
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $response[$i]['results'],
        'post_content'  => $response[$i]['content'],
        'post_status'   => 'draft',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'custom_pt'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
}
```

I doublechecked the response of the API and I'm sure the correct data is sent to the function, also I tried the function inserting just one post and works fine, so I would like to know if there is some limitation to use the function (I have not found anything at the codex) or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks :).

Edit: I've actually tried using a request to wp-json/wp/v2/posts, also I catch the response with

```
if( !is_wp_error( $post_id ) )
```

and return the response stored un $post_id (it returns nothing, the site just does nothing and I have to restart apache to re enable it).

Comment: Have you checked the response of `wp_insert_post`? I see lots of things happening but none of them are checked to see if they succeeded or not. `$response` might be empty, `file_get_contents` might fail ( have you considered using the WP HTTP API instead? )

Comment: I've edited the question, and I forgot to say that I've also tried with curl to fetch the API, I'm shure it works :).

Comment: `$response[i]` should be `$response[$i]`.

Comment: Lol, sorry guys, it's just a demostrative code, not the code I'm actually using, the logic of an 'wp_insert_post' calling by a loop is what I'm trying to express. And sorry for my mistakes, it actually works but when you want to do this don't do it in a custom template, use a function at functions.php or an endpoint :).

Comment: you can run any code in a loop.

Comment: @J.RobertoRamirezMatias if this question is still 'alive' maybe you want to post the actual code you're using?

Comment: Thank you for answering @mozboz, the issue was that I was calling the function directly on a custom template, I moved it to functions.php and called from the template and it worked.